# Este if se muestra, pero no tendría que mostrarse

Tags: php, if

Ya había echo un tema, pero era con las horas, ahora es con los días, y lo tengo exactamente igual, que se muestre de una fecha en adelante hasta una determinada fecha, pero, en el ejemplo ya paso la fecha, igual se muestra.

```html
        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
            <div class="row">
                  <?php
                  if($quediaes!="Sat" && ("08-09-2018" <= $fecha || $fecha <= "17-09-2018")){
                   include('sabado.php'); 
                 }
                   ?>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Creo que tienes un error en tus signos de comparacion ya que son ambos `<=` luego del `&&` interpreto que quieres comparar dentro del rango de las fechas `09-09-2018` y `17-08-2018` en este caso no estas haciendo eso

Comment: haz un print de tus variables para descartarlos de primera

Comment: `$fecha = date("d-m-Y");`

Comment: eso está dentro del rango ya que  `08-09-2018" <= $fecha (18-09-2018) `es decir 8 es menor que 18como mencionó @YoAlbert tienes que revisar tus operadores

Comment: @YoAlbert Como hago para comparar las dos fechas entonces, quiero hacer que se muestre desde una fecha hasta la otra

Comment: `if($quediaes!="Sat" && ("08-09-2018" >= $fecha || $fecha <= "17-09-2018")){
                   include('sabado.php');`

Comment: resulta curioso que lo hagas de esa manera, puesto que en el código de ejemplo estas comparando CADENAS y no fechas... Si eso funciona es fruto del azar. Para trabajar con fechas, es recomendable que utilices objetos DATETIME. Y si acaso, que conviertas primero la fecha a un timestamp y lo compares como si fueran numeros.

Comment: Tienes alguna guía de lo que hablas?

Comment: puedes buscar por internet "uso de fechas en php". Te recomendaria que vieras las funciones de php en el manual `http://php.net/manual/es/ref.datetime.php` , y `https://blog.trescomatres.com/2014/06/trabajar-con-fechas-en-php-1/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No sé exactamente qué estás intentando porque me falta el contexto de la otra pregunta.

Como sea, yo veo dos problemas.

**Primero**: Si estás comparando strings la comparación es en orden alfabético, por lo que se cumple

```
08-09-2018 < 09-02-2018
```

Simplemente porque 9 es mayor a 8, y a PHP no le importa que el segundo valor sea febrero.

Una manera sencilla de obviar este problema es convertir el formato `DD-MM-YYYY` en  `YYYYMMDD`. Incluso comparando alfabéticamente queda claro que

```
20180908 > 20180209
```

**Segundo**: Supongamos que ya hiciste el reemplazo. La condición

```
("20180908" <= $fecha || $fecha <= "20180917")
```

*Siempre se cumple*. Todo momento desde que empezó el universo hasta el 17 de septiembre cumple con la segunda condición. Todo momento desde el 8 de septiembre hasta que se acabe el universo cumple con la primera.

Creo que tu condición debe ser:

```
("20180908" <= $fecha && $fecha <= "20180917")
```

Cuando arregles eso, no te conformes con la solución parche de seguir comparando por strings. Usa las funciones nativas de PHP para comparar fechas y a la larga el tiempo invertido en eso se pagará con creces.

Comment: Gracias, tuve un problema con la otra solución y al final probé esta y parece que funciona, pero a que funciones nativas te refieres, para comprar fechas? Quiero, como dijiste, algo final y no un parche.

Comment: Me equivoqué, recién retomo este caso, y $fecha muestra "2018201820182018OctOctSatSat" NADA QUE VER. Esa variable es cualquier cosa....